# Foreground service permission

Tags: android, android-service, foreground-service

In my application I have a foreground service that I start like that:

```
reactContext.startService(new Intent(reactContext, MyService.class));
```

And then in `onCreate` of the service I call:

```
startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID_FOREGROUND, createForegroundNotification("message"));
```

After reading about `foreground service` I noticed that I have to add specific [permission](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/foreground-services#request-foreground-service-permissions) if my app targets api 28:

> Note: If an app that targets API level 28 or higher attempts to create
> a foreground service without requesting the FOREGROUND_SERVICE
> permission, the system throws a SecurityException.

I didn't add this permission to my manifest and I didn't get any exception when the service starts to run. Is it because of the way that I start this service, because in the example from the docs the service is started like this:

```
context.startForegroundService(intent);
```

and it's not what I do.
Should I add this permission anyway?

Comment: Yeah, weird behavior. The same to me, start foreground service successfully without FOREGROUND_SERVICE permission.

Answer (score 0):

Faced this issue recently.
Resolved it by upgrading the target sdk version 33.
Got this reference from here:https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/notifications/notification-permission#new-apps

Code:
This is the handler

```
val pushNotificationPermissionLauncher = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.RequestPermission()) { granted ->
       //handle code after permission granted
    }
```

This is the launcher for the permission:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
pushNotificationPermissionLauncher.launch(android.Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS)
}
```